# Chilli Plant turned brown

Tags: plant-health, chili

I need help to revive my chilli plant. The plant was beautiful and produced lots of chiili in summer.when winter started leaves dried out as expected. Now the winter is almost over with last minth left and my plant turned brown. Is this normal, if not how can i bring the plant back to life. I have atttached a photo. [image]

Comment: To better answer your question, please provide an appropriate location of where you live. Chilli plants are often grown as annuals because, depending on your geographical location, they die back heavily in winter and sometimes do not survive. Some people go to the extreme measure of digging them out of the ground, transplanting into pots and moving them indoors for winter.

Comment: *appropriate = approximate

Comment: Thank you for replying Andrew. I live in Melbourne, Australia and the winter here is pretty cold specially at night.

Answer (score 1):

Chilli plants as with all plants in the Genus *Capsicum* do not survive cold weather in temperate climates such as Melbourne, Australia.

While the chilli plant is known as a short lived perennial - it will actively grow for more than two years - it will only survive outdoors for more than one year in tropical climates.

For this reason, in subtropical and temperate climates, the chilli plant is often grown as a long season annual.

Some gardeners go to the extreme measure of digging their chilli plant/s out of the ground in autumn (while they are still actively growing), transplanting them into pots and moving them indoors for winter.

The best advice for your situation... wait.

If it has not already perished, moving your chilli plant now will almost definitely cause its permanent demise.

My advice is to wait until spring and see whether the plant sends out new growth.

There are signs of life in the stem - a small amount of green.

If you have the energy and enthusiasm, you could set up a shroud or cover for the plant using four stakes as support and some clear "builders" plastic sheeting.

At this late stage, this is no guarantee for survival and your time and money may be better spent on a bag of cow manure for the soil and a new chilli plant to grow indoors in a pot for the next month until your Spring weather begins.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response.